# Moving label looks good in Firefox - not so good in other browsers How to change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I wrote a small script to let a label move out of the way everytime the corresponding input field is needed.

Please check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/5nZWJ/68/

The problem is: it works just as expected in Firefox, but all other browsers I tried (Chromium, Internet Explorer and others) don't keep the bottom-border justified (hard to explain but you will see it if you try it out).

What do I have to change to make this thing in all browsers look like in Firefox?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I got identical jsfiddle results in Chrome and FF5 on OSX

Comment: Ah hah! Did not notice the bump on the first run - it appears during the beginning of the animation.

Comment: interesting - is it a "good" result (bottom-border justified) or a bad result?

Comment: Turned out to be wrong what I wrote. If you press pause during the animation at http://jsfiddle.net/a2kva/4/ Chrome displays the correct px values (they sum up to 77px) but the line is broken. So the other answer is correct probably: it's kind of a rounding issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved your problem. It is now smooth in all browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/5nZWJ/70/

The key is having `#formWrapper` positioned absolutely from the *bottom*. This means when the height is increased it expands from the bottom up and doesn't need to recalculate the position from the top.

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 110px;
    width: 500px;
    position:relative; /* Allows absolute figures to be predictable */
}

#formWrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    border-bottom: 4px solid red;
    bottom: 29px; /* Changed from top and new measurement added */
    left: 120px;
    height: 57px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 108px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

I removed all lines of code referring to the position, as it no longer needs to be changed or recalculated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be related how different browsers count border pixels

http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

(not actually the same problem, but you get some idea)

Instead of using border, I recommend you add a *div* wrapper around the element, with the background color set to border color and padding set to the border width.

Comment: thanks. hm, as the border property doesn't change, how could this be related?

Comment: If the Y position of the element is not integer due to animatino the border hits a subpixel position and different browsers place it differently.

Comment: subpixel = the same as rounding issue, as in other answer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gEFrn/1/
seems like it's not directly related to borders (erased the borders in this example) however, you might be right...